# arch -i386 ipython notebook Error

Tags: python, 32bit-64bit, macports, jupyter-notebook

I have installed all the required packages to run the ipython notebook using macports with the +universal build option. I can run ipython with arch -i386 ipython without a problem. I have successfully opened the notebook using the 64bit build. However, when I try to open the notebook in 32bit mode I get the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/zmq/__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
    from zmq.utils import initthreads # initialize threads
ImportError: dlopen(/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/zmq/utils/initthreads.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/zmq/utils/initthreads.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/IPython/utils/zmqrelated.py", line 35, in check_for_zmq
    import zmq
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/zmq/__init__.py", line 54, in <module>
    raise ImportError("%s\nAre you trying to `import zmq` from the pyzmq source dir?" % e)
ImportError: dlopen(/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/zmq/utils/initthreads.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/zmq/utils/initthreads.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
Are you trying to `import zmq` from the pyzmq source dir?

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/local/bin/ipython", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('ipython==1.2.1', 'console_scripts', 'ipython3')()
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 118, in start_ipython
    return launch_new_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 544, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 89, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/IPython/terminal/ipapp.py", line 312, in initialize
    super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).initialize(argv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 89, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/IPython/core/application.py", line 373, in initialize
    self.parse_command_line(argv)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/IPython/terminal/ipapp.py", line 307, in parse_command_line
    return super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).parse_command_line(argv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in parse_command_line
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 89, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 474, in parse_command_line
    return self.initialize_subcommand(subc, subargv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize_subcommand
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 89, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 405, in initialize_subcommand
    subapp = import_item(subapp)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/IPython/utils/importstring.py", line 42, in import_item
    module = __import__(package, fromlist=[obj])
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/IPython/html/notebookapp.py", line 36, in <module>
    check_for_zmq('2.1.11', 'IPython.html')
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/IPython/utils/zmqrelated.py", line 37, in check_for_zmq
    raise ImportError("%s requires pyzmq >= %s"%(required_by, minimum_version))
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If the port that installed `/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/zmq/utils/initthreads.so` is installed with the universal variant (use `port provides $file` to find out which port that is), that's a bug in said port. Please file a ticket about this.